# MySQL: Left Join, concat or sum, unrepeated rows

Tags: mysql, left-join, concatenation

I'm making a referral system from scratch. Have 2 tables: "USERS" and "PAYMENTS". Each row in payments is an individual payment for maybe, the same user.

I need to show our associated, how many referrals they have, how many are in the free plan, and how many have paid a subscription.

I have been done this for now:

```
 SELECT u.user_id
      , u.email
      , u.package_id
      , u.date
      , u.package_expiration_date
      , u.country
      , u.utm_id
      , p.amount 
   FROM users u 
   LEFT 
   JOIN payments p
     ON p.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE u.utm_id = 2;
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the user_id "1" has paid, two times, the amount of $24.5.
**I need this in a single column for show the total amount paid ($49)**, and the in PHP makes some percentage kind.

Any tips?

Comment: It's a good idea to show sample data and expected output , Good as in better than showing non desired  output with the code that produced it..

Comment: Im not sure if i understand, please forgive my english. 
I need the user_id 1 in a single row, with amount value = 49

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick aggregation should do the trick,removed the other columns for ease

```
SELECT 
   `users`.`user_id`, `users`.`email`,`users`.`utm_id`,
  SUM(payments.amount)  as total_sum
FROM `users`    
LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`utm_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`, `users`.`email`
```

Comment: Awesome, i will leave the complete code for reference purposes. Thank you very much.

Comment: SELECT `users`.`user_id`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`package_id`, `users`.`date`, `users`.`package_expiration_date`, `users`.`country`, `users`.`utm_id`, sum(`payments`.`amount`) as total
FROM `users` 
 LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`utm_id` = '2'
GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`, `users`.`email`